# Subscription getting too late in the execution angular

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, angular2-observables, auth-guard

I'm new to angular and my subscription getting late in execution. I can't use Async Pipes as I'm using custom libraries in my project. here is the subscription function.

```
loadOrganizations() {
    console.log("loading organizattions");
    this.getOrganizations().subscribe(
      (results) => {
        const organizationList = [];
        if (results.organizations) {
          results.organizations.forEach((element) => {
          this.appendOrganization(element, organizationList);
            this.loadChildrenOrganization(element.children, organizationList);
          });
        }           
       this.organizations$.next(organizationList);
       this.organizations$.complete();
       console.log('organizationList in here', organizationList); 
       return this.organizations$.asObservable();
      },
      (error) => {
        this.organizations$.next([]);
        this.organizations$.complete();
      }
    );
  }
```

any clue or suggestions to execute this before executing the next lines. I'm calling this function in my authguard.ts inorder to call this function before initializing my component.

Comment: Are you want to execute loadOrganizations() first then other functions ?

Comment: @C.Ellawla, your function return always null (the return inside a subscribe never happens). You should avoid subscribe in a library. Remember: "services return observables, we subscribe to the observables in components". re-think your function using rxjs operators: forkJoin, swithMap... NOTE: If you return observables of course you can use async pipe.